# Mongoose adding new entry to parent

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mongoose

I'm building a REST API with express and mongoose. I have the following schemas :

```
var PostSchema= new Schema({
name: String,
_comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'}]
});

var CommentSchema = new Schema({
text: String,
_post: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post'}
});
```

I want to add a new comment to my post :

```
/* POST a comment*/
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
var comment= new Comment(req.body);
comment.save(function (err, post) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
    res.json(post);
});
});
```

It does save the comment with the following data :

```
{text: "bla", _post: *postId*}
```

However, when I retrieve my posts with populated comments :

```
/* GET post*/
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
Post.find().populate('_comments').exec(function (err, posts) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(posts);
});
});
```

The comments array is empty.

So I guess that when I'm adding a new comment to a post, I also need to add the comment id to the post.comments array  and save it ? Is there a clean way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After saving `comment` (in callback passed to `comment.save`), add it to `post._comments` with [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/). You will avoid duplicates by doing this.

```
Post.update({ _id: comment._post }, { $addToSet: { _comments: comment._id } }, {}).exec();
```